# How can I determine my EOS RAM byte-by-byte?

Tags: eos

I want to review my EOS token RAM byte-by-byte.

How can I see this?

I am specifically trying to determine what gets allocated on account creation.

Comment: Why do you care about memory allocated on account creation?

Comment: you can follow this  answer  https://eosio.stackexchange.com/questions/2041/can-i-get-the-current-ram-usage-in-contract/2046#2046

Comment: This is different than what I want. I want to see my current user account's RAM usage - specifically where each byte is allocated. Is there a guide on how RAM is allocated?